# Unable to save file in DBFS

Tags: azure, csv, apache-spark, databricks

[image]I have took the azure datasets that are available for practice. I got the 10 days data from that dataset and now I want to save this data into DBFS in csv format. I have facing an error :

" No such file or directory: '/dbfs/temp/hive/mytest.csv'"

but on the other hand if I am able to access the path directly from DBFS. This path is correct.

My code  :

```
from azureml.opendatasets import NoaaIsdWeather
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


spark.sql('DROP Table if exists mytest')
dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/tmp/hive",recurse = True)

basepath = "dbfs:/tmp/hive" 

try:
  dbutils.fs.ls(basepath)
except:
  dbutils.fs.mkdirs(basepath)
else:
  raise Exception("The Folder "+ basepath + " already exist, this notebook will remove in the end")

dbutils.fs.mkdirs("dbfs:/tmp/hive")

start_date = parser.parse('2020-5-1')
end_date = parser.parse('2020-5-10')

isd = NoaaIsdWeather(start_date, end_date)
pdf = isd.to_spark_dataframe().toPandas().to_csv("/dbfs/temp/hive/mytest.csv")
```

What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: `isd.to_spark_dataframe().toPandas().to_csv("dbfs:/temp/hive/mytest.csv")` try this or without `dbfs:`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @srinivas
I have tried with both ways but same issue.

Comment: you're creating directory `/tmp/hive`, but you're writing into `/temp/hive` - notice unnecessary `e`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @alex
It is the type mistake in the question. In actual code I am using tmp everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the same issue. First I have used the following code and made sure that the directory exists using `os.listdir()`.

```
from azureml.opendatasets import NoaaIsdWeather
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
spark.sql('DROP Table if exists mytest')
dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/tmp/hive",recurse = True)
basepath = "dbfs:/tmp/hive" 
try:
  dbutils.fs.ls(basepath)
except:
  dbutils.fs.mkdirs(basepath)
else:
  raise Exception("The Folder "+ basepath + " already exist, this notebook will remove in the end")

dbutils.fs.mkdirs("dbfs:/tmp/hive")

import os  
os.listdir("/dbfs/tmp/hive/")
```

[image]

- Then I used the following to write the csv using `to_pandas_dataframe()`. This has successfully written the required dataframe to csv file in required path.

```
mydf = isd.to_pandas_dataframe()  
mydf.to_csv("/dbfs/tmp/hive/mytest.csv")
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the details reply. @Bhaanu
I have added the following :

import os  
os.listdir("/dbfs/tmp/hive/")

mydf = isd.to_pandas_dataframe()  
mydf.to_csv("/dbfs/tmp/hive/mytest.csv")

but it still give me same error:
No such file or directory: '/dbfs/tmp/hive/'

Comment: Can you please check if `os.listdir("/dbfs/tmp/hive/")` is working or is it giving the same error?

Comment: It is also giving the same error.

Comment: This indicates that the required directory was not created properly. Please recheck if the necessary directory has been created properly or not. I have used the same code and it worked fine for me. Please refer to [this image](https://i.imgur.com/wA543j8.png).

Comment: Go to `Settings -> Admin Console ->Workspace Settings` and enable DBFS FIle Browser. Now go to `Data ->DBFS` and check if the directory `/tmp/hive/` is created successfully after running the code.

Comment: I have already added enabled the setting which you are saying. 
/tmp/hive/ already created when I have checked.  I am assuming it is created by default. like /user/hive is already in the DBFS tab

Comment: Directory is created successfully. I made another directory for test it also show in DBFS tab .

Comment: Are you still getting same error ?

Comment: Yes.
I have tried all steps you were suggested. 
I have tried to show the dataframe data by using display(df). It show the data successfully.
you can see the latest code in the updated question image

Comment: @BhanunagasiVamsi 
any other thing I should try.

Comment: Considering `os.listdir("/dbfs/tmp/hive/")` is giving path not found error, there must be a problem creating the directory. If the directory is created successfully, there is no reason for `to_csv()` to throw path not found error (since it is correct syntactically).